# Drush archive-dump database dump failed on XAMPP

Tags: drush, backups

I want to import my local drupal site in another machine. This is what I ran from DOS from drupal root folder to get my site archive

```
drush archive-dump --destination=mysite.com.tar.gz
```

After few seconds it just stop after this message

```
Database dump failed.
```

I see the mysite.com.tar.gz file is created with my webroot fils. I don't think it created any db dump file which sounds obvious because of that error message.

These are mysql.ini settings (note the modified settings commented inline)

```
key_buffer = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 2M -- THIS WAS 1M
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
log_error = "mysql_error.log"
[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 32M -- THIS WAS 16M
```

What do I need to do create archive without this error? I am open for other alternatives too (other than manually ftp and dumping db file)